# Exposing web service in mule

Tags: web-services, mule, cxf, anypoint-studio

I want to expose a web service. I have WSDL file with me. I am using CXF proxy service as operation. Now, I have doubt that in Inbound attributes value of port,namespace & service should take from WSDL file only,Right?
If yes, then, after deploying through, http://localhost:8081?wsdl this link am not getting same WSDL which I want to expose.
So, tell me where am I going wrong?Thanks.

To test the project, which URL should use in SoapUI, so that appropriate request XML will generate...

Here is my flow,

```
<flow name="meterreadingdocumenterpresultbulkcreateconfirmation_outFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:proxy-service configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration" port="MeterReadingDocumentERPResultBulkCreateConfirmation_OutPort" namespace="http://sap.com/xi/IS-U/Global2" service="MeterReadingDocumentERPResultBulkCreateConfirmation_OutService" payload="body" doc:name="CXF"  validationEnabled="true"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/>
     </flow>
```

After exposing a web service I am not getting proper response...

Comment: there should be endpoint adress of your port, for example http://localhost:8081/yourContext/yourService?wsdl

Comment: yourContext means port name which we give in CXF? Then its showing resource found. I have added the code. Please help me with that.